# Issue with getting icons for applications

Tags: c++, windows, qt

I want to get icons for all installed applications (using registry) on Windows. The problem is:

```
QObject::connect: Cannot queue arguments of type 'QList<QIcon>'
(Make sure 'QList<QIcon>' is registered using qRegisterMetaType().)
```

I'm connecting data from `Worker`class

```
QThread *programsThread = new QThread();
Worker *programsWorker = new Worker();
programsWorker->moveToThread(programsThread);
connect(programsWorker, &Worker::appData, this, &Test::setAppData);

QList<QIcon> programIcons;
emit appData(programIcons, displayNames, displayVersions, publishers, installLocation, uninstallLocations);
```

and in `Test` class setting data in `QTreeWidgetItem` (`QTreeWidget`)

```
void setAppData(QList<QIcon> icons, QStringList names, QStringList versions, QStringList publishers, QString installLocation, QStringList uninstallLocations);
```

I have tried `Q_DECLARE_METATYPE(QIcon)/qRegisterMetaType<QIcon>("QIcon");` but no luck. Can someone display how to use it?

How to fix it? Thanks in advance.

Comment: The error says that `QList<QIcon>` is not known, so how should `qRegisterMetaType<QIcon>("QIcon")` help? It makes `QIcon` known to the meta system. Try `qRegisterMetaType` for `QList<QIcon>`.

Comment: @Lorenz

Thank you. It works.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to @Lorenz

I have changed code to: `qRegisterMetaType<QList<QIcon>>("QList<QIcon>");` and it works now.